# Objective-C WebKit framework to get access token from Facebook

Tags: objective-c, facebook, macos, webkit

I had found some info in internet that it is possible to get access token from Facebook through WebKit framework. Is it true? If yes, then how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can post a request to the Facebook API and get a valid access token back or use the [Facebook iOS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/) to log the user in.

```
-(NSString *)loadAccessToken{
    NSString *accessTokenURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&grant_type=client_credentials",client_id, client_secret];

    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:accessTokenURL]];  
    [request startSynchronous];

    NSMutableString *accessMutable = [[request responseString] mutableCopy];
    [accessMutable replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"access_token=" 
                               withString:@"" 
                                  options:NSLiteralSearch 
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [[request responseString] length])];

    return accessMutable;
}
```